# css3 - How to achieve shadow & then line?

Tags: css

I want above **Hello** shadow line should be shadow and then line ( I mean inverse of below line). Please help me how to achieve this.

```css
.fusion-separator.sep-shadow {
  height: 1px;
  overflow: visible;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0)), color-stop(15%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65)), color-stop(85%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 0%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 15%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65) 50%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 85%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 0%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 15%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65) 50%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 85%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 0%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 15%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65) 50%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 85%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 0%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 15%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65) 50%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 85%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 0%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 15%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65) 50%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 85%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000',endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1);
}
.fusion-separator.sep-shadow:after {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% -50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 65%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% -50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% -50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% -50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 65%);
}
```

```html
<div class="fusion-separator fusion-full-width-sep1 sep-shadow"></div>
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Hello</h1>
<div class="fusion-separator fusion-full-width-sep sep-shadow"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this new class. I used `CSS` property `transform` to rotate the above div `.fusion-full-width-sep1`.

```
.fusion-full-width-sep1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9zvx8y75/

Answer (score 0):

I did it by positioning the shadow as `absolute` and the `sep-shadow` as `relative`.
I also moved the margin to `sep-shadow`.
You can play with the `top` attribute of `.fusion-separator.sep-shadow:after` to move the shadow

```css
.fusion-separator.sep-shadow {
  position:relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: visible;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0)), color-stop(15%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65)), color-stop(85%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 0%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 15%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65) 50%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 85%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 0%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 15%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65) 50%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 85%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 0%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 15%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65) 50%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 85%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 0%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 15%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65) 50%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 85%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 0%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 15%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65) 50%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 85%, rgba(150, 150, 150, 0) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000',endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1);
}
.fusion-separator.sep-shadow:after {
  position: absolute;
  top:-3px;
  display: block;
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% -50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 65%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% -50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% -50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% -50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 65%);
}
```

```html
<div class="fusion-separator fusion-full-width-sep1 sep-shadow"></div>
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Hello</h1>
<div class="fusion-separator fusion-full-width-sep sep-shadow"></div>
```